# RestKit network limits blocks other calls when parallel requests are running

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, rest, restkit, restkit-0.20

we are facing a problem.
we have background requests that are downloading files constantly (up to 5MB each file). meanwhile, we have a UI that most navigations require REST calls.

we limited the number of background downloads so it won't suffocate the operationQueue that RESTkit uses.

when several files are downloaded in background, we see the network usage with 1->2 MB (which is understandable).

**The problem is:** the user navigates through the app, and each navigation calls a quick REST call that should return very little data. but because of the background downloads, the UI call is taking forever (~10 seconds).

Priority did not help, i saw that the UI call i make instantly is handled by the operation queue (because we limited the downloads limit and the NSOperationQueue had more space to fulfill other requests.

when we limited the concurrent REST download calls to 5 - the REST calls from the UI took 10 seconds.
when we limited the concurrent REST download calls to 2 - everything worked fine.

the issue here is that because we let only 2 downloads occur in the background - the whole background operation of downloading files will take forever.

the best scenario would be that every UI call would be considered as most important network-wise and even pause the background operations and let only the UI call to be handled - then resume the background operation - but i'm not sure it's possible.

any other idea to address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 `RKObjectManager`s so that you have 2 separate queues, then use one for 'UI' and the other for 'background'. On top of that you can set the concurrent limits for each queue differently and you could suspend the background queue. Note that suspending the queue doesn't mean already running operations are paused, it just stops new operations from being started.

By doing this you can gain some control, but better options really are to limit the data flow, particularly when running on a mobile data network, and to inform the user what is happening so they can accept the situation or pause it till later.

Comment: the thing is, the separate NSOperationQueue queues are not the cause of the problem here. we tried doing that and it didn't help - same result (stuck UI).

we did restrict the concurrent download operations so the the queue will still have slots to handle UI requests.

so there's no different between 1 or 2 RKObjectManagers as i see that the UI call is immediately handled by the queue. but the logic inside (probably the network stuff) is taking so much time.

only when limiting to 2 downloads in parallel the UI worked fine. it's abit of a bummer :( any other idea?

Comment: The bottle neck is likely to be the mapping as each manager runs mapping single threaded IIRC.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: 2 `RKObjectManager`s will have 2 different queues for networking and mapping, and mapping always runs single threaded in an RKOM so that connections can be made sensibly.

Comment: mapping is such a big overhead? i saw that the next item in my queue starts after one of the big downloads finishes. that's why i thought it's networking bottleneck

Comment: It depends what the mapping is, how many items there are, what connections are to be made, what caching you're using - many things can impact the processing time. If you turn on more logging it will tell you the network and mapping time for each request...

Comment: @ArielB were you able to solve ur issue using two object managers?

Comment: @xs2bush nope, did not work, we limited our parallel network usage eventually.